# fail2ban filter not matching - is it regex or something else

Tags: fail2ban

I have a website with a php script that is allowed to be called infrequently.  Some annoying users are hitting my script every few seconds and I need to ban them.  I have setup failban but they are not being caught.  I've read the wiki and modeled my setup after examples.  Can someone tell me what is not right here?

First my jail:

```
[my-checkversion]
enabled  = true
filter   = checkversion
logpath  = /data/logs/mydomain.com-access_log
findtime = 60
bantime = 86400
maxretry = 6
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

Next my filter:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = apache-common.conf
[Definition]
# Example
# 144.217.80.24 - - [02/May/2019:07:02:00 -0500] "POST /hidden/readversion.php HTTP/1.1" 200 -
failregex = ^<HOST> - - \[.*\] "POST <checkversion_url> HTTP/1\.[01]" 200 .*$
ignoreregex =
[Init]
checkversion_url = /hidden/readversion.php
```

I placed a 1 line excerpt from the apache access file showing a user hitting the URL in question in a comment above the regex line.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?  Is it the regex?  The online regex editors won't help because of the variable substitutions...so this is a best effort

Comment: Why are you substituting variables anyway? Isn't it static? If so, a simple `failregex = readversion` or similar should suffice, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an option with fail2ban to force it to look at a file to try your rules, and it prints out if it works or not.

Have you looked at `fail2ban-regex <logfile> <fail2ban rule .conf>` ?

Comment: I didn't see any reference to it in my original research, but it's there and works.  Problem solved